# File rename in UI intermittenly available in UI

Tags: google-drive-api

We are seeing that when a user changes the name of the file in the Docs, Sheets, or Slides UI and then attempts to export the file from Drive using a custom application built using the Drive SDK that the name of the exported file is the old name, not the new name.  The content is the latest revision. This occurs intermittently.

Is this a bug? Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: how quickly after the rename are you doing the export? If you delay, do you see the expected results? The thing with Drive is that all updates are asynchronous and have variable propagation delays.

Comment: @pinoyyid you have a source for that regarding async? Im interested because in years of using the api ive never seen any async operation. However, recently many things have started to fail in drive. There is another Q in s.o. about a newly created file not appearing in a search inmediately after creation but it wasnt like that until a few weeks ago.

Comment: It's always been that way. Internally you can think of Drive as a massively distributed database. Read performance is excellent, but write performance is limited (to put it politely). This is why write operations so quickly trip up over rate limit problems, and why under certain circumstances, write updates aren't immediately processed. This manifests itself in things like search indexing and thumbnail creation and (a long time ago) md5/etag values. Because it's a timing thing, under normal running it's invisible, but hardware/network/config issues can intermittently expose it.